# Intel RST on ubuntu 23.04 for NVME Raid1 - array is not assembled / started

Tags: raid, mdadm, nvme, rst

I have 4x nvme drives installed on Z690 motherboard:

- 1tb nvme with fresh install of windows 11 Pro
- 1tb nvme with fresh install of Ubuntu 23.04 Desktop
- 2x 2tb nvme for Raid1 array created in BIOS using Intel RST

The array works perfect in Windows but when I boot to Ubuntu it's not assembled / started, I have found the below partial solution on this forum

```
sudo IMSM_NO_PLATFORM=1 mdadm --verbose --assemble --scan
```

however every time I restart the PC I need to run this command again from terminal, how can I make it permanent and auto-mount the array at start?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was an issue for me too on 23.04, however it is now fixed in 23.10. I'm also using a Z690 motherboard.

In future, you can use systemd to create and enable a service that you can use to run a command on startup. [This](https://linuxhandbook.com/create-systemd-services/) is a great resource for learning how to do that.